# Cómo diseño un algoritmo que contenga un subprograma de cálculo del factorial de un número y una llamada al mismo

Tags: algoritmos, lenguaje-agnóstico, factorial

```
entero función factorial(E entero:n)
var
entero: i,f
//advertencia, segun el resultado, f puede ser real
inicio
f ← 1
desde i ← 1 hasta n hacer
f ← f * i fin_desde
devolver (f)
fin_función
```

y el algoritmo que contiene un subprograma de cálculo del factorial de un número y una llamada al mismo:

```
algoritmo función_factorial
var entero: x, y, numero
inicio
escribir ('Deme un numero entero y positivo')
leer(numero)
x ← factorial(numero)
y ← factorial(5) escribir(x, y)
fin
```

Comment: Bienvenida Ximena, te recomiendo que visites los siguientes enlaces: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Podrías agregar mayores detalles por favor? html, html5, ajax, xhtml están sobrando, si lo que quieres es desarrollar en algún lenguaje de programación, puede ser C++, C, Python, Java, PHP, C# por ejemplo. Lo importante es que intentes y si te quedas en algún punto, toda la comunidad te dará una mano con la mejor de las intenciones para que continues desarrollando :D. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Ximena. ¡Bienvenida a [es.so]! No me queda del todo claro cuál es la pregunta. ¿Podrías [edit] tu publicación para explicar cuál es la respuesta que estás buscando?

Comment: si, queria realizar el codigo fuente con esos datos, pero no estoy segura de como se hace, es de una funcion. y son subprogramas :), gracias por interesarse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que andas buscando es un algoritmo recursivo. Estos algoritmos, requieren una condición de salida, para no dejar pegado el computador. El algoritmo debiera ser algo así:

```
factorial (entero n):
    si entero n==0
        retornar 1
    si no
        retornar n*factorial(n-1)
```